# get selected radio button from group

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

iam trying to do it in 2 ways, and both times value is "".  i need to get value-"id" of radion button if it is selected.

**Way 1**

```
 var selected = $("#step-1 input[type='radio']:checked");
                if (selected.length > 0) {
                    var answerIDQ1 = selected.val().id;
                }

                var selected = $("#step-2 input[type='radio']:checked");
                if (selected.length > 0) {
                    var answerIDQ2 = selected.val().id;
```

**Way 2**
                    }

```
                if ($("input[type='radio'].group1").is(':checked')) {
                    var answerIDQ1 = $("input[type='radio'].group1:checked").val().id;

                }

                if ($("input[type='radio'].group2").is(':checked')) {
                    var answerIDQ2 = $("input[type='radio'].group2:checked").val().id;

                }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="step-1">
                <h2 class="StepTitle">
                    <label style="font-weight: bold; color: #662819;" id="frage1"></label>
                </h2>
                <br />

                <input type="radio" class="group1" name="group1" id="frage1antwort1" value="" onmousedown="this.__chk = this.checked" onclick="if (this.__chk) this.checked = false" />
                <label id="antwort1fuerFrage1"></label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <input type="radio"  class="group1" name="group1" id="frage1antwort2" value="" onmousedown="this.__chk = this.checked" onclick="if (this.__chk) this.checked = false" />
                <label id="antwort2fuerFrage1"></label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <input type="radio"  class="group1" name="group1" id="frage1antwort3" value="" onmousedown="this.__chk = this.checked" onclick="if (this.__chk) this.checked = false" />
                <label id="antwort3fuerFrage1"></label>
            </div>

            <div id="step-2">
                <h2 class="StepTitle">
                    <label style="font-weight: bold; color: #662819;" id="frage2"></label>
                </h2>
                <br />

                <input type="radio"  class="group2" name="group2" id="frage2antwort1" value="" onmousedown="this.__chk = this.checked" onclick="if (this.__chk) this.checked = false" />
                <label id="antwort1fuerFrage2"></label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <input type="radio"  class="group2" name="group2" id="frage2antwort2" value="" onmousedown="this.__chk = this.checked" onclick="if (this.__chk) this.checked = false" />
                <label id="antwort2fuerFrage2"></label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <input type="radio"  class="group2" name="group2" id="frage2antwort3" value="" onmousedown="this.__chk = this.checked" onclick="if (this.__chk) this.checked = false" />
                <label id="antwort3fuerFrage2"></label>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the the `id` of the checked attribute, use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr)

```
var answerIDQ1 = selected.attr('id'); // or selected[0].id
```

`selected.val().id` tries to get the `id` property of the `value` of the selected radio